# Rails 4+ Edit multiple objects in one form BEST PRACTICE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-form-for

I have a User, Drinks, Gyms, Foods Model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :drinks
 has_many :foods
 has_many :gyms
end
```

I track the number of drinks a user had during the day and save it in the database.I do the same with Foods and Gyms.

I have a User and a Session (for login) controller. So far I haven't needed a controller for my "passiv" Models (Drink, Food, Gym).

Now I have one page with a form on which the User can change the entries of all tables(Drink, Food, Gym) of the previous day.

I think I need to use fields_for in the form to edit objects of multiple Models in one form.

However I don't know how many controllers I need and where I should put in all the business logic... I don't want to do anything quick and dirty, but rather follow certain Best Practices.

My approach so far:

- A lot of forms on one page

  ```
  <%= form_for :running, url: data_update_user_path do |f| %>
  <%= form_for :drinks, url: data_update_user_path do |f| %>
  <%= form_for :food, url: data_update_user_path do |f|
  ```
- One DataController who handles all the different updates (It's basically a big if elsif)

  ```
  class DataController 
   def update

    if params[:drinks]
     #update drinks
    elsif params[:foods]
     #update foods
    elsif params[:gyms]
     #update gyms
    end
   end
  end
  ```

So my question: What is the best practice in such a situation?

Answer (score 2):

Use nested form with only one controller; the users controller, the update action for the user will update it's related models as well when you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` so basically your user model will be

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foods
  has_many :drinks
  has_many :gyms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :foods, :drinks, :gyms
end
```

And the for for user will contain `fields_for` foods, drinks and gyms

Don't forget in your users controller if you are using strong_parameters to permit the attributes of the nested models

```
def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:id, .... , foods_attributes: [:id, :destroy, ....], gyms_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, ....], drinks_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, ....])
end
```